# bootstrap layout with collapsible footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a layout like below. The top header (non-sticky) and bottom notifications panel. We are planning to display scrollable text in the notifications panel. We would also like to have user to collapse this panel down, so that he can only see this when he wants to.

1. How can I design a such a layout using bootstrap (I am using the latest version)
2. The height of the notifications panel can be fixed via css.

I tried the following markup but I am having following issues with it.

1. I am not able to set the percent height (to support different monitors) for the bottom div
2. I do not know how to make it collapsible (bootstrap accordion may be?).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Heading</h3><hr/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <h4>Notifications</h4><hr/>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used bootstrap `accordion` instead of `collapse` as I wanted to allow user to click on the title (div) rather than any link or button. Please see the code snippet attached.

```css
.bottom0.panel-group  {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.notifications-scroll-area {
    height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid body-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3>Admin Home</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
      <a href="@Url.Action(" NewConfiguration ")" class="btn btn-link"><span class="text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>&nbsp;New Configuration</span></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-link"><span class="text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>&nbsp;Manage Configuration</span></a>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="panel-group bottom0" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Notifications 
                        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse notifications-scroll-area" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body ">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>TimeStamp</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Message</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>22/11/2014</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-info">INFO</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>Execution started.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>22/11/2014</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success">SUCCESS</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>Execution completed.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>22/11/2014</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-danger">ERROR</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>Execution failed.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>22/11/2014</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-info">INFO</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>Execution started.</td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To collapse when the title (class="panel-heading") is clicked put `data-toggle` on the div instead of a button.

Comment: That was great!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use bootstraps [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Here's a simple example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Heading</h3><hr/>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Toggle
</a>
<div id="collapseExample" class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
<h4>Notifications</h4><hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript/jQuery to hide this. Just create an element (probably an 'X' or something) with an ID of 'notifications_toggle' and use this as javascript.

```
$('#notifications_toggle').click(function(){
  $('.scrollable_notifications').toggle();
});
```

You can also use javascript to switch the x into an arrow or something so the user knows they can click it again to re-open the notifications bar.

Here's more info on jQuery toggle()

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You could also use show() / hide()

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: This works, however since the question is tagged Twitter Bootstrap the first answer involves lest "custom javascript".

Comment: Unless you're using Bootstrap's collapse elsewhere in your application, I'd advocate for removing this section of Bootstrap and using custom javascript to keep your application as lightweight as possible.

Comment: I just don't like Bootstrap / front end frameworks. There is some merit to them speeding up prototypes; however, I think they make developers lazy.

Comment: Granted, but he did specify "in bootstrap", also if you are going to enable some toggle functionality in plain jQuery, it will be more DRY to create a collapsable class and add it toggle functionality based on that and some data attribute (mind you this is how Bootstrap does it.)

Comment: Not sure what about my function isn't DRY (nothing in it is repeated); however, if he is already using Bootstrap then it's probably easier for him to implement Bootstrap's collapse.